# How do I update a value IN a map?

Tags: apex, map

In looping through a result set I fill a map with objects. Once the loop is completed though, there is a condition which requires me to update 1 of the values in the first instance of the map. How do I do this?

In a list it's easy:

```
list[0].field = 'abc';
```

How do I do this for a map?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you have the key for the first element, you can simply do

```
YourMap.get(Key).field = newValue;
```

if you don't have the key for the first element, then you can try

```
List<Id> mapKeys = new List<Id>(yourMap.keySet());
YourMap.get(mapKeys[0]).field = newValue;
```

Comment: Hm, actually I'm getting an error of 'Expression cannot be assigned' with my sobjectmap (tried casting to the appropriate object which didn't fix it)

Comment: What worked for me was overwriting the value by using the map put method with the key. This also retains the order of the map set and values. You can test it with the code below      `Map<String,String> mapOrderTest = new Map<String,String>();     
mapOrderTest.put('1','a');     
mapOrderTest.put('2','b');     
mapOrderTest.put('3','c');     
mapOrderTest.put('4','d');     
System.debug('Value of mapOrderTest prevalueUpdate: ' + mapOrderTest);     
mapOrderTest.put('2','Beta');     
System.debug('Value of mapOrderTest postValueUpdate: ' + mapOrderTest);`

Comment: @SamKamensky changing one item inside a record (while leaving the rest of the record as-is) in a map to an object data type requires more complex syntax than changing the single value in a map to a primitive data type.